# Select a folder or a file

Tags: qt

Is there a way in Qt to use just one dialog in order to select either a file or a folder?

What I mean is that I'd like to have an option, let's call it select, and by using this user could, from the same dialog, pick either a folder or a file.

Comment: it seems that there isn't. How about writing your own file dialog class? If no, then I'd just use two different actions, one for files, the other for directories

Comment: @zebrilo ok fair enough. Own file dialog class may be the way to go. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a built in widget, but it is easy enough to connect a QDirModel to a QTreeView and get the selection signals.

Here is an example to get you started:

**test.cpp**

```
#include <QtGui>

#include "print.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QDirModel mdl;
    QTreeView view;
    Print print(&mdl);

    view.setModel(&mdl);
    QObject::connect(
        view.selectionModel(),
        SIGNAL(currentChanged(const QModelIndex&,const QModelIndex&)),
        &print,
        SLOT(currentChanged(const QModelIndex&,const QModelIndex&)));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**print.h**

```
#ifndef _PRINT_H_
#define _PRINT_H_
#include <QtGui>

class Print : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        Print(QDirModel* mdl);
        ~Print();
    public slots:
        void currentChanged(const QModelIndex& current, const QModelIndex&);
    private:
        QDirModel* mModel;
        Q_DISABLE_COPY(Print)
};

#endif
```

**print.cpp**

```
#include "print.h"

Print::Print(QDirModel* mdl) : QObject(0), mModel(mdl) {}
Print::~Print() {}

void Print::currentChanged(const QModelIndex& current, const QModelIndex&)
{
    qDebug() << mModel->filePath(current);
}
```