# Picking either a file or a folder in QtQuick

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I'm using QT6 for working with DICOM (`.dcm`) file format. It can be presented either as a file or a folder. I want to use a picker, that allows me to pick folder and files.

As I see [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-filedialog.html#selectFolder-prop), the Qt 5.15 allows that by `selectFolder` property, but in Qt 6.x is was removed.

As I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224208/select-a-folder-or-a-file) now it requires a C++ hack for it.

Can it be done with a QML tools in Qt6? (Qt 6.4 to be more precise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Qt5.x you had FileDialog and, yes, it did have a selectFolder boolean which could only be true or false. Not both. So, you cannot have a single FileDialog that allows you to select either file or folder at the same time.

In Qt6.x you have FileDialog and FolderDialog. So, again, you cannot have a single dialog that allows you to select either file or folder at the same time.

Instead, you can consider rolling your own. As a starting point, you can consider using `Qt.labs.folderlistmodel` so you needn't create any code in C++. The following is a demonstration of how you may go about creating a file/folder dialog that works with both files and folders (it is a demo only, and, by no means complete):

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Page {
    FileFolderDialog {
        id: fileFolderDialog
        folder: "file:///tmp"
        nameFilters: ["*.*"]
        onAccepted: result.text = fileUrl
        onRejected: result.text = "rejected"
    }
    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: qsTr("Open")
        onClicked: fileFolderDialog.open()
    }
    footer: Text {
        id: result
    }
}

// FileFolderDialog.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel
Dialog {
    id: fileFolderDialog
    x: (parent.width - width) / 2
    y: (parent.height - height) / 2
    implicitWidth: 500
    implicitHeight: 400
    property alias folder: folderModel.folder
    property alias nameFilters: folderModel.nameFilters
    property url fileUrl
    standardButtons: Dialog.Ok | Dialog.Cancel
    ListView {
        id: fileFolderView
        anchors.fill: parent
        clip: true
        currentIndex: -1
        model: FolderListModel {
            id: folderModel
            folder: "file:/tmp"
            nameFilters: ["*.*"]
        }
        delegate: ItemDelegate {
            icon.source: folderModel.isFolder(index) ? "folder.svg" : "file.svg"
            width: ListView.view.width - 20
            text: fileName
            checkable: true
            onClicked: {
                fileFolderView.currentIndex = index;
                fileFolderDialog.fileUrl = fileFolderDialog.folder + "/" + fileName
            }
        }
        highlight: Rectangle { color: "lightsteelblue" }
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
            width: 20
            policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
        }
    }
}

// one.txt
tst

// two.txt
tst

// three/three-a.txt
tst

// three/three-b.txt
tst

// four.txt
tst

// folder.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><path d="M30 7H16l-1-2H5L4 7H2v20h28zm-1 19H3V12h26zm0-15H3V8h1.618l1-2h8.764l1 2H29z"/><path fill="none" d="M0 0h32v32H0z"/></svg>

// file.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><path d="M27 9.699L19.3 2H5v28h22zM26 29H6V3h12v8h8zm-7-19V3l7 7z"/><path fill="none" d="M0 0h32v32H0z"/></svg>
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

References:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-dialogs-filedialog.html
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-dialogs-folderdialog.html
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qt-labs-folderlistmodel-folderlistmodel.html